# How to hide collider gizmos when hidding it in the inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working with a group of friends on a project and somehow we managed to hide the collider gizmos when it is also hidden in the inspector. We do not know how we manage to do that and I want to recreat it again.

I will explain this better with images.
[image: Screenshot 1]
As you can see, the collider is hidden in the scene view.

[image: Screenshot 2]
but in here, when I open the components the collider also appears.

How can i recreat this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of unity.
To actually scene the `Gizmos` you have to enable it in Scene window
[image: Screenshot]

Now, when `Gizmos` is enabled you can see them, and when you collapse the component in the inspector, that Gizomo will be hidden. When you expand the component, you can see that Gizmo in the Scene.